# Updating iOS 8 -> iOS 9 (New version of Swift) Causes REST API Issues (401 Error) using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, rest, ios9, alamofire

After I updated my code from iOS 8 to iOS 9, my alamofire rest calls started giving me 401 errors. The code works perfectly fine in iOS 8 but not in iOS 9.

Thanks for the help.

The fullUrl and token variables are set correctly.

```
let fullUrl = Config.baseUrl + endpoint
let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
        manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic \(token)"
        ]

        manager.request(.GET, fullUrl).response {
            (request, response, data, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print("GET REQUEST: \(response.statusCode)")
                print(response.debugDescription)
//                print(response.description)
                if response.statusCode == 200 ||
                    response.statusCode == 201 {
                        let json = JSON(data: data!)
                        success?(json: json)
                }
                else if response.statusCode == 403 {
                    UserInfo.logOut()
                    failure?(error: .ExpiredToken)
                }
                else {
                    failure?(error: .InvalidLogin)
                }

            } else {
                failure?(error: .ConnectionUnavailable)
                //                    self.log(request, res: response, err: error)
            }
        }
```

In my info.plist I have also added the code to handle App Transport Security

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Please let me know if there is any confusion with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into the same issue I had: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/798

Your URL might return a redirect, in wich case the "Authorization"-Header is not passed along. You can test this when you look at the data sent over the network using Wireshark or a similar tool.

If you don't want to do the network debugging, you can just try the following and see if you're request work.
BTW: You should not use HTTPAdditionalHeaders.

Try this:

```
// Configure special-handling of redirects (you only need to do this once)
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
    var redirectedRequest = request

    if let
        originalRequest = task.originalRequest,
        headers = originalRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields,
        authorizationHeaderValue = headers["Authorization"]
    {
        let mutableRequest = request.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableRequest.setValue(authorizationHeaderValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        redirectedRequest = mutableRequest
    }

    return redirectedRequest
}


// Your code, slightly adapted
let fullUrl = Config.baseUrl + endpoint
let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": userData.userAPIKey!,
        ]
Alamofire.request(.GET, fullUrl, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: headers)
  .response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
       if let response = response {
            print("GET REQUEST: \(response.statusCode)")
            print(response.debugDescription)
            //                print(response.description)
            if response.statusCode == 200 ||
                response.statusCode == 201 {
                    let json = JSON(data: data!)
                    success?(json: json)
            }
            else if response.statusCode == 403 {
                UserInfo.logOut()
                failure?(error: .ExpiredToken)
            }
            else {
                failure?(error: .InvalidLogin)
            }

        } else {
            failure?(error: .ConnectionUnavailable)
            //                    self.log(request, res: response, err: error)
        }        
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So it looks like the header isn't being passed. I changed it to how you suggested, but still having the same issues.

Comment: Could you veriy that a redirect occurs? If so, try to change your url to prevent the redirect and see if that works.

Comment: Helped me! Perfect! I was on the ropes here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the possibilities is due to the `ATS` because `iOS` 9 and `OSX` 10.11 require TLS Version 1.2 SSL that enforce you for secure connections between an app and its back
end so you should use HTTPS exclusively. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with
forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain you have to specify this domain in your app's
Info.plist file.

```
<Key> NSAppTransportSecurity </ key>
<Dict>
 <Key> NSExceptionDomains </ key>
 <Dict>
  <Key> yourserver.com </ key>
 <Dict>
      <-! Include to allow subdomains ->
      <Key> NSIncludesSubdomains </ key>
      <True />
      <-! Include to allow insecure HTTP requests ->
      <Key> NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads </ key>
      <True />
      <-! Include to specify minimum TLS version ->
      <Key> NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion </ key>
      <String> TLSv1.1 </ string>
    </ Dict>
  </ Dict>
</ Dict>
```

if you application needs to connect with unknown hosts you have to configure like this.

```
<Key> NSAppTransportSecurity </ key>
<Dict>
    <-! Connect to anything (this is probably BAD) ->
    <Key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </ key>
    <True />
</ Dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, actually the `sessionManager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders` get overwritten by the `requestSerializer` when sending the request. So you must set the headers in the `requestSerializer`, not in the `session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders`.

Code that was working on iOS8, but not on iOS9:

```
sm.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Bearer \(token!)"]
```

New code for iOS9

```
sm.requestSerializer.setValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that was fixed by temporarily allowing Alamofire to accept invalid SSL certificates (not for shipped code, but it works until the server is equipped to handle it).

```
public let alamoFireManager = Manager(
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [
        "myserver.com": .DisableEvaluation
        ])
)
```

and to use it, call

```
alamofireManager.request(....
```

like you would a normal request.